# How to detect React Native Flat list completely re-rendered when extra data changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, frontend, react-native-flatlist

In React Native, we know that the Flat list component has a property that is called "extra data". When the extra data changes, the Flat list will be re-rendered. So how do we know that the Flat list is completely re-rendered or not?
For example: before the Flat list is re-rendered -> show loading -> the Flat list is completely re-rendered -> turn off loading.

Comment: whenever extraData changes, flatlist always re renders.

Comment: @GauravRoy but I mean is there a way to detect when the flat list is completely re-rendered? Ex: event or callback or something likes that

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.memo for that, here's something you can try but there are other better approaches like why-did-you-render and devtools

(use this for debugging only, but don't keep it in your code)

At the top of the file outside your main component:

```
const MemoizedFlatList = React.memo(FlatList,(prevProps, nextProps)=>{
   const areEqual = prevProps === nextProps
   if(!areEqual ){
      console.log('Rerendered')
      for (var key of Object.keys(prevProps)) {
         if(prevProps[key] !== nextProps[key]){
              console.log(key)
         }
      }
   }
   return areEqual 
   
})
```

now use `<MemoizedFlatList />` instead of `<FlatList />` inside your component to debug

Comment: So when 'Rerendered' is logged that means it has done an unnecessary rendering right?

Comment: the equal function is a place holder, you need to add some better comparision that actually compares the values correctly, not every rerender is useless tho, maybe something has changed and rerendering there is correct and expected